How to copy text from my web game that I hosted on Itch.io?
I am having trouble copying specific text to the clipboard in a game I developed in Unity that I am hosting directly in the browser on Itch.io.
The code I implemented works perfectly in the editor and when I run the application using Visual Studio Code (Live Server), but never in the application hosted on the Itch.io website.
I want to emphasize that I am not violating any Itch.io guidelines. In fact, I was able to copy texts from other games, most of which were made in Python (mainly visual novels) and one in Scratch. I searched for several games developed in Unity, but none of those I found had any visible input fields or text chat, and given the sampling, I found that sufficient.

Below are two screenshots proving that it is possible to copy:



Initially, I tried passing the text that I wanted to be sent to the clipboard in a method that was called upon clicking a button.
Code.cs:


#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endif

//usings and class declaration...

#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    static extern void CopyToClipboard(string copyText);
#endif

    public void WordToGepeto()
    {
        string _word = "";
        
        //logic...

        _word = _word.TrimEnd();
        CopiarParaClipboard(_word);
    }

    public void CopiarParaClipboard(string _texto)
    {
#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
        CopyToClipboard(_texto);
#else
        GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = _texto;
#endif
    }



Code.js (inside the Plugins folder located in Assets):


mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    CopyToClipboard: function(copyText) {
        var text = UTF8ToString(copyText);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
            console.log('Texto copiado para a área de transferência com sucesso!');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Falha ao copiar texto: ', error);
        });
    }
});



This was the error that appeared:

[Violation] Permissions policy violation: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See https://goo.gl/EuHzyv for more details.


Forca.framework.js:3 Falha ao copiar texto:  NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See https://goo.gl/EuHzyv for more details.

The link does not lead anywhere (Error 404).

After that, I tried to modify the iframe, but it's only possible to read it.


Later, I gave up using a button and created an InputField to manually copy the text (using control + c). To my complete surprise, even that didn’t work. No error appears, it just doesn’t copy.

Below are other things I tried before coming to ask for help:

I changed the Unity version (from 2020.3.37f1 to 2021.3.18f1).

I tried adding this code (<meta http-equiv="Permissions-Policy" content="clipboard-write=(self)">) in the header of the index.html file in the build.

I switched browsers (I tried Edge, as I was previously using Chrome), and it presented the same error that was appearing before.



In a final attempt, I tried changing the Chrome settings, trying to force access to the clipboard (see image below), and even disabling its default protection, but nothing worked.


I will be immensely grateful for any help provided.

Do these help at all? How to copy text from an InputField to the clipboard in WebGL? or Can text within an iframe be copied to clipboard?

@DMGregory Your comment helped me a lot. Based on it I was able to achieve my goal. I have given credit. If there is something missing in the answer, please let me know.

I'm very glad! Great work finding a solution!

DMGregory's comment (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) led me to a question with a similar issue.
The question: How to copy text from an InputField to the clipboard in WebGL?
In it, the user recommends a repository, which is apparently obsolete: https://github.com/greggman/unity-webgl-copy-and-paste
However, there is a link to the most up-to-date repository: https://github.com/Trisibo/unity-webgl-copy-and-paste
I still can't put the text directly to the clipboard, but I can copy the text from Input Field. To do this, you just need to import the package into the project. If you are using the TMPRO package, just uncomment a line.
All of this is highlighted in the instructions:

